# Do we want MathJax support on 3D Printing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, mathjax

[MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) support allows questions and answers to contain pretty mathematical formulae, easy subscripts & superscripts, fractions, roots and greek letters etc. all using LaTeX syntax.

I have seen at least one answer so far which included an equation, so might have benefited from having MathJax markup enabled.

It is apparently easy for the Stack Exchange team to enable, we just need to decide whether we want it or not.

See my [MathJax reference post on Robotics meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/131/37) for some examples of what MathJax can do.

Comment: It's not a matter of simply enabling it. Mathjax requires significant resources for users to load it, so our guidance is to have everyone start gathering a collections of questions that illustrates a significant *need* for Mathjax before we enable it.  Carry on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we get MathJax enabled?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/can-we-get-mathjax-enabled)

Comment: @Glorfindel It looks like I was 2 years and 7 months too early with my question, and you were another 1 year and 7 months too late with your comment. *8')

Answer (score 1):

At this time, I don't think this would provide a significant enhancement to the site.

The 3D printing industry is both blessed and cursed in terms of development. While software and general usability is relatively easy compared to traditional manufacturing technologies, the general lack of digital feedback from the machine makes it difficult for the end user.

With this in mind, I find it difficult at this point in time to include 3D printing-related formulas. Most other math-based questions will most likely be [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) related or [Software](https://stackoverflow.com/) related which I think is still a grey area here on the 3D printing site.

Comment: I just did a reply that would have been easier to write if there was Latex