# Can we get MathJax enabled?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, formatting, mathjax

Our site is dealing with electronics and practical engineering, so we use formulas in questions and answers on occasion, most usually when we have to figure out electronic ratings.

When we talk about the [design](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/760/analytic-equations-to-make-algorithm-of-3d-printer) or [function](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/631/how-are-delta-movements-calculated) of printers more than "rule of thumb", we need complex math. When we estimate [print times](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4472/how-is-the-print-time-of-an-object-to-be-printed-estimated?s=4%7C17.5425) formulas could be used to illustrate the calculations. When we want to estimate the [length of a spool of filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/is-the-110m-length-accurate-for-3-0mm-1k-spool), we need math. When we discuss [movement paths](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/5155/8884), we also come into need for 3D geometry which can be simplified by using non-carthesian coordinates or functions - which in turn need manual typing of greek letters or proper formulas to be displayed well.

Up to now I have been typing LaTeX formulas in online converters and copy paste the link to the image generated formula. This is quite labor intensive, especially since the SE does support built in MathJax.

A recent [answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6540/5740) showed LaTeX/MathJax code in the answer, but that did not render into an actual formula image as it is not enabled.

> - Supply voltage $ U_S = 12V \or 24V $
> - Logic Voltage $ U_L = 5V $
> - Sensor Voltage $ U_sens = U_L$
> - Temperature control (Hotend/Bed/Cooling fans) $ U_T = U_S$

Why can't we enter formulas directly in posts?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable request and there are already a fair number of posts that would benefit. Two things to consider: 1) it will add extra page load time to each question (even those that don't use MathJax) and 2) the dollar sign is usually the right delimiter, but some topics need that symbol for other purposes. If y'all are willing to take the overhead and decide on a symbol, I'd be glad to turn MathJax on for y'all.

Comment: @JonEricson I put the discussion about the symbol up onto https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/which-character-to-use-to-activate-mathjax/342#342 - jsut so we can pin our vote down. `$` and `~` are only used occasionally and then as single characters, so both wouldn't create problems. On the other hand, we could rule out other standard characters as useful: §, %, &, * and # all have legitimate uses in either the 3D printing directly or in borderline cases (e.g. § when we need to talk copyright stuff, * to denote annotions at times, # for "generic number" or weights)

Comment: @JonEricson - Hi Jon, and thanks in advance for sorting this out. `$` is the chosen symbol, in keeping with Robotics et al.. Looking forward to having it turned on.

Comment: Now that we have it enabled, thanks to Jon, you can accept ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\text{3D Printing Stack Exchange} \subset \text{Stack Exchange sites that use MathJax}$$

There are [~17 posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/3dprinting/query/879802/mathjax-inline)  that could use an edit. Most of those are prices that have been converted into MathJax. You can fix that by escaping the dollar sign:

```
$ => \$
```

I'll work on those edits myself, but I'd love to get some help.

Comment: We'll go through the list! Thanks for enabling.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I am away from a keyboard until Late Sunday unfortunately. Restricted to iPhone only so I can't do much.

Comment: I went through those couple posts I made where I knew I had used it already as a markup sign (2 cases), checking out the rest. Thanks again Pal!

Answer (score 4):

MathJax would be really helpful:

We recently discussed [How is infill generated via slicing?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6832/how-is-infill-generated-via-slicing/6836#6836) and the answer is linear algebra. Displaying linear algebra without formulas is a PITA.