# Which character to use to activate MathJax?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, mathjax

We were offered to [get MathJax enabled](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/can-we-get-mathjax-enabled).

Now, we need to decide on which character to have text between them parsed into MathJax! So please either add your suggestion or cast your vote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's stay with the classic $.

Example: \$\$\frac{1 \times 2}{2} = 1\$\$

---

*Now that MathJax is enabled, it renders to:
$$\frac{1 \times 2}{2} = 1$$*

Comment: Yes, classic please ($ and $$)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the majority has ruled! :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative character could be the Tilde `~`.

Comment: We should stay consistent with other sites. Robotics uses $, and maybe Mathematics

Comment: @Greenonline That is a very good reason to go for $, I wonder which character is used by other sites that have MathJax enabled.

Comment: Just checked on Robotics, and a $ on its own is rendered correctly, so I cant see a problem.

Comment: Math and RPG use $

Answer (score 0):

Dollar works in isolation. See:

> [image]

However, two (seemingly unrelated) dollar signs *will* cause a problem, see [Weird behaviour when using two (2) $ signs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315381/weird-behaviour-when-using-two-2-signs), such as this:

```
* Build a $1 Billion home ([Mukesh Ambani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilia_(building)))
* Build a $1.2 Billion Yacht ([Roman Abramovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(yacht)))
```

Comment: You can even have $ as part of the equation. Existing posts can potentially become broken, I think that is the only risk. Clearly, they can be edited as soon as we find them.

Comment: Thanks Sean, just updated image