# Can we get mhchem support?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax, formatting

We got [MathJax enabled](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/can-we-get-mathjax-enabled). Today I learned that there is even more! We could have [**support for Physical units** enabled as part of the mhchem package](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9710/can-we-extend-mhchem-support-in-mathjax-to-include-physical-units?cb=1)! We use physical units **a lot** and demand the SI formatting. Let me quote from Worldbuilding:

> Chemistry Stack Exchange is obviously the main consumer of this feature and has a [nice FAQ on its use](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9710/can-we-extend-mhchem-support-in-mathjax-to-include-physical-units?cb=1). The chemists get two things that we don't:
>
> - `\require{mhchem}` is implicit... you get support automatically without having to require it explicitly.
> - They get physical unit formatting via `$\pu{273.15 K}$`, which currently renders as a grumpy error on WB.SE and WB meta that looks [with only mhchem enabled] like this [image: mathjax markup error]

**Can we have that too? Pretty please?** I am tired of having to type `$273.15\ \text{K}$` and such, especially if it is complex things in the unit!

Comment: I wonder if we need to ask someone directly (either on Meta or the TL), for example [Catija](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9751)

Comment: @Greenonline: Mods can escalate Meta posts for staff attention by adding the [status-review] tag, as detailed in this MSE post: [What posts should be escalated to staff using \[status-review\], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast - OK, just seen this. OK, acting upon it shortly, thanks.

Comment: OK Trish, I've added the status-review tag, a month too late... sorry for not acting earlier... it's been too hot to think (that's my excuse that I'm sticking to) :-)

Comment: @Greenonline no problem, we are few, and it is low priority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deed is done. Behold! In all its glory:

$$\pu{273.15 K}$$

Comment: Nice one! Thanks Slate :-)

Answer (score 2):

I support this request for people that do want to use the support for physical units.

*(vote up this answer if you are in favor)*

---

For values and units I haven't used the MathJax notation (only for complex equations), I've always used the html characters for formatting values and units.

The example from the question would be written as:

```
273.15&nbsp;K
```

which renders to "273.15 K"

or in Celsius:

```
0&nbsp;&deg;C
```

which renders to "0 °C".

The drawback of using the LaTeX style from MathJax (and presumably with mhchem support) is that the rendered value and unit are in a different font, for example:

| Text rendering | MathJax rendering | MathJax code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 273.15 K | $273.15\ \text{K}$ | `$273.15\ \text{K}$` |
| 0 °C | $0\ ^\text{o}\text{C}$ | `$0\ ^\text{o}\text{C}$` or `$0\ ^\circ\text{C}$` |

Comment: mhchem *also* allows to write chemical fomulas and other things: `$\ce{H2O}$` renders a very nice, non italicised $H_2O$

Comment: Can't you put the `\text` before the number/quantity as well, so you get the same font? See [this comment](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9710/can-we-extend-mhchem-support-in-mathjax-to-include-physical-units?cb=1#comment31298_9710)

Answer (score 0):

I do not support this request to support physical units.

*(vote up this answer if you are not in favor)*